# Released build of app cannot seem to read firestore db

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've got a flutter app using firestore which works great in the debug build. I've pushed an alpha test of the build to the google play store, but the downloaded version of the app cannot seem to connect to the firestore DB. I must have configured something wrong with the firestore plugin, but I've already re-done the install/configure steps multiple times and it's not having an effect.

In the firebase console, under "Authentication", I can see the user on the physical device getting authorized, but no firestore traffic seems to be getting through.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that you will get a useful answer based on that much information. You should investigate this on your own a bit more.

You should find your `build.gradle` file. It's usually at `/android/app/build.gradle`. Inside that change the release build to be debugable. Something like this:

```
android{
    ...
    buildTypes {
      ...
      release {
          debuggable true
      ...
      }
    ...
    }
}
```

after this you will be able to build a release version locally and debug it to figure out what is the problem with you release version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a typo (cut/paste error) in the SHA key I put into firebase console. Aaargh. So difficult to debug. Fixed now.